# Дублирование кода html страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Есть страница

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и код

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.globalcontainer {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 4%;
    height: 100%;
}

.header > .header__text {
position: relative;
width: 93px;
height: 24px;
left: 0;
margin-top: 129px;
margin-bottom: 20px;

font-family: TT Norms;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 100%;
/* identical to box height, or 24px */


color: #000000;
}

/*
.header__buttons {
    left: 0;
    top: 193px;
}
*/


.header__button {
    width: 75px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-color: #5f3ec0;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-right: 1.75%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.header__buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 7px 15px 7px 0px;
    /*margin-right: 10%;*/
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
}

.cardexample {
    width: 100%;
}

.mobileimage img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.mobiles {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.content__title {
    font-family: TTNorms-Medium;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 21.6px;
    
    margin: 0.3% 15px 0 15px;
}

.crashvideo {
    width: 115px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    
    background-color: #5f3ec0;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.video__icon {
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

#ex2 {
    display: none;
}

.youtube__icon-play {
    margin-left: 30.5px;
    margin-top: 20.5px;
    
    align: center;
}

.content__text {
    margin-top: 16px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 90px;
    
    font-family: TT Norms;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 150%;
    /* or 22px */


    /* Main text */

    color: #cacaca;
}

.endlink {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    
    font-family: TT Norms;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 100%;
    color: #121212;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css">-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mobile.css" media="screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 639px)"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/tablet.css" media="screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1023px)"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/desktop.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1920px)"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="globalcontainer">
        <div class="header">
                <div class="header__text">
                    Обзоры
                </div>
                <div class="header__buttons">
                    <!-- <span> -->
                        <button class="header__button">Все</button>
                        <button class="header__button">Видео</button>               
                        <button class="header__button">Текст</button>               
                        <button class="header__button">Обзоры</button>
                        <button class="header__button">Сравнения</button>
                        <button class="header__button">Краш видео</button>
                        <button class="header__button">Распаковка</button>
                    <!-- </span> -->
                </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="content">       
                <div class="cardexample">
                    <div class="mobileimage">
                        <img class="mobiles" src="../img/mobileimage.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content__title">
                        Iphone 11, почему такой же как и Pro Max, может быть большим в 3 строки вот так
                    </div>
                        <div class="video__icon">
                            <span>
                                <button class="crashvideo">Краш видео</button>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <a href="#"><img class="youtube__icon-play" src="../img/Vector.png"></a>
                            </span> 
                            <span>
                                <button class="crashvideo" id="ex2">Краш видео</button>
                            </span>                         
                        </div>
                    <div class="content__text">
                        Видео разбор с ответами на самые часто задаваемые вопросы может быть большим в 3 строки, видео разбор с ответами на самые часто задаваемые
                    </div>
                    <div class="endlink">
                        <a href="#">Читать далее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cardexample">
                        <div class="mobileimage">
                                <img class="mobiles" src="../img/mobileimage.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content__title">
                            Iphone 11, почему такой же как и Pro Max, может быть большим в 3 строки вот так
                        </div>
                        <div class="video__icon">
                            <span>
                                <button class="crashvideo">Краш видео</button>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <a href="#"><img class="youtube__icon-play" src="../img/Vector.png"></a>
                            </span> 
                            <span>
                                <button class="crashvideo" id="ex2">Краш видео</button>
                            </span>                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="content__text">
                            Видео разбор с ответами на самые часто задаваемые вопросы может быть большим в 3 строки, видео разбор с ответами на самые часто задаваемые
                        </div>
                        <div class="endlink">
                            <a href="#">Читать далее</a>
                        </div>              
                </div>
                <div class="cardexample">
                </div>
                <div class="cardexample">
                </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsactions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Как избавиться от дублирования кода

```html
                <div class="cardexample">
                        <div class="mobileimage">
                                <img class="mobiles" src="../img/mobileimage.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content__title">
                            Iphone 11, почему такой же как и Pro Max, может быть большим в 3 строки вот так
                        </div>
                        <div class="video__icon">
                            <span>
                                <button class="crashvideo">Краш видео</button>
                            </span>
                            <span>
                                <a href="#"><img class="youtube__icon-play" src="../img/Vector.png"></a>
                            </span> 
                            <span>
                                <button class="crashvideo" id="ex2">Краш видео</button>
                            </span>                         
                        </div>
                        <div class="content__text">
                            Видео разбор с ответами на самые часто задаваемые вопросы может быть большим в 3 строки, видео разбор с ответами на самые часто задаваемые
                        </div>
                        <div class="endlink">
                            <a href="#">Читать далее</a>
                        </div>              
                </div>
```

Comment: А этот код генерируется серверной стороной? Или просто как статичный html? Таких блоков будет много или нет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: на самом деле, здесь "XY problem" уже полгода ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский этот код - просто статический html. Таких блоков 8.

Comment: @UModeL интригующе.

Comment: @itspec891 Вы принципиально не отмечаете "галочкой" ответа на Ваши вопросы?

Comment: @Igor все опробовал и отметил (на все нужно время).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведу лишь пример. Я думаю по образу и подобию вы сделаете.

Заводим массив объектов с основными данными (например картинка, заголовок и текст), создаем метод, который отдаёт шаблонную строку с *HTML*, которая как раз дублируется по сто раз на странице и далее пробегаемся циклом по изначальному массиву вызывая метод с шаблоном и формируя контент. Далее этот контент вставляем в нужный элемент.

```js
// Массив объектов с данными, которые нужно применять в каждом повторяющемся блоке
let data = [
    { img: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/a9/3c/b4/a93cb4e0316ef9c4db83846550ff4deb.jpg', title: 'Заголовок 1', text: 'Полный текст 1' },
    { img: 'https://vjoy.cc/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/1-13.jpg', title: 'Заголовок 2', text: 'Полный текст 2' },
    { img: 'https://klike.net/uploads/posts/2018-06/1528641366_2.jpg', title: 'Заголовок 3', text: 'Полный текст 3' },
    { img: 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/37/26/27/3726273afdaf29d8eb0312a34b85874b.jpg', title: 'Заголовок 4', text: 'Полный текст 4' },
];

// Функция, которая возвращает один элемент повторяющегося шаблона
// с вставкой в него переменных
const getRowTemplate = (img, title, text) => {
    return `
        <div class="row">
            <img src="${img}" />
            <p>Заголовок новости таков: ${title}</p>
            <p>А вот основной текст новости:</p>
            <div>${text}</div>
        </div>
    `;
};

// Функция, которая пробегается по всему массиву и на каждой итерации
// подставляет данные из одного элемента массива в функиwb. взятия шаблона Html
const getAllNews = (data) => {
    let content = '';
    
    data.forEach(el => {
        content += getRowTemplate(el.img, el.title, el.text);
    });
    
    return content;
};

// Функция рендера всего контента на основе переданных данных
const renderAllNews = (data) => {
    document.getElementById('news').innerHTML = getAllNews(data);
};

renderAllNews(data);
```

```css
.row {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

img {
  width: 70px;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="news"><div>
```